# cursor.execute(...) for string prefix search

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Suppose I have want to do a string prefix search in database, say

```
select * from some_table where name like 'abcde%';
```

where `abcde` is actually some user input string.  How do I do it in MySQLdb in python?  I could think of two ways:

```
cursor.execute("""select * from some_table where name like '%s%%'""", (some_prefix_to_search))
```

OR

```
cursor.execute("""select * from some_table where name like %s""", (some_prefix_to_search + '%'))
```

Which one is the correct way?  For method 1, will MySQLdb correctly figure out '%s%%' is a whole, so it will generate 'abcde%' instead of something like ''abcde'%', i.e. will %s be substituted as the string value with or without the quote mark?

For method 2, will the % in the input string be thought as some special value and escaped?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method will not work; mysqldb will quote your input value again and the query will throw a syntax error.

Your second method works because the `execute` method only needs to consider `%` a special character in the query template string, so that it can identify placeholders and decide where to insert parameters. It has no reason to consider `%` a special character in the parameter values themselves because `%` is not a character that can be used for SQL injection.